# Can I use a C++ object creation optimisation with QTimers and signals?

Tags: c++, qt, optimization

I'd like to implement this: http://lynxline.com/stack-vs-heap-pimpl-performance/ with a particular object which will be created many times and needs to be as fast as possible.  However in my object I have QTimers with connected slots which are not started until after the constructor.

My question it would this method still work with the QTimer()'s and their respective signals and slots? Or is it limited to objects which don't instantiate others?

This is the optimization example:

```
template <int def,int real>
struct check_d_size : ::static_assert::is_fail<(bool)(def == real)> {};

class StackObj {
public:
    StackObj() {
        check_d_size<d_size,sizeof(Private)>();
        d = new(d_bytes) Private;
    }
    virtual ~StackObj() { d->~Private(); }

private:
    class Private {
    public:
        inline void * operator new(size_t, quint8 * mem) { return mem; }

        int i;
        int j;
        DynObj * p;
        std::string str;

        class Check {
        public: Check() { static bool b=true; if (b) { qDebug() << "ok new stack"; b = !b; } }
               ~Check() { static bool b=true; if (b) { qDebug() << "ok del stack"; b = !b; } }
        } chk;
    };
    Private * d;
    static const int d_size = 32;
    quint8 d_bytes[d_size];
};
```

This is my constructor:

```
PenPathDetails::PenPathDetails(DiagramScene *parent, int penId) :
    m_parent(parent),
    m_penId(penId),
    m_originalPenId(-1)
{
    m_AutoJoinTimer = new QTimer();
    m_AutoJoinTimer->setSingleShot(true);
    m_MouseLastMovedTimer = new QTimer();
    m_MouseLastMovedTimer->setSingleShot(true);

    connect(m_AutoJoinTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slotGroupPaths()));
    connect(m_MouseLastMovedTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slotMouseReleased()));

    reset();
    resetOriginalPenId();
}
```

Comment: I don't see the relation between your StackObj and PenPathDetails::PenPathDetails. Or am I missing something?

Comment: BTW, thanks for the link. VERY interesting...

Comment: Koying, there is no relationship right now, I want to make PenPathDetails use the same method of creation as StackObj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimization happens when you do the memory allocation of your private class.
Wherever you allocate it, it will be faster due to the fact that it is allocated on the stack rather than on the heap.

Assuming `PenPathDetails` is your private class, it is its allocation which will be faster, the allocation of the QTimer stuff in the ctor of the class will stay constant unless you allocate your QTimer's on the stack, too, i.e. `QTimer m_AutoJoinTimer` rather than `QTimer* m_AutoJoinTimer`